# How to resolve "ajax 403 error forbidden in CAKEPHP 2.x"

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

i'm trying to access data using ajax call in cakephp but getting 403 forbidden error, given below.

```
GET http://localhost/ec/bazar/Products/color_switcher/3 
403 (Forbidden)
jquery.js:6 
x.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.js:6 
x.extend.ajax53:251 
colorSwitcher53:327 
onclick
```

i'm using this code to make call

```
function colorSwitcher(id){

        var testid = id;
       $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>Products/color_switcher/' + testid,
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error in ajax call");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#img-portion").html(data);
                },
            });

    }
```

controller

```
public function color_switcher($testid = ''){
      $this->layout= 'ajax';
}
```

color_switcher.ctp

```
<?php echo "helooooooo"; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of struggle i find out solution

If you are using Auth, you need to make sure that you are logged in if the controller/action is not on your `$this->Auth->allow()` list.

or simply make it allow for public access by

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('action name');
    }
```

in my case 'action name' will be  color_switcher

Make sure you set debug to 0 as well, might cause you some problems.

explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507568/cakephp-403-on-ajax-request) by @Dunhamzzz